# How to match a view borders with other borders?

Tags: android

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_title"
        android:text="Crime Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/crime_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/crime_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output:

[image]

As you can see the button goes beyond the border that is composed by these two TextViews, but i want it to accurately match it. I also tried to do it with LinearLayout that have two LinearLayouts instead of RelativeLayout but I didn't succeed. **So how can i do it ?**

Comment: Does it need to be in a RelativeLayout or it's ok to use other, for example ConstraintLayout?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I just didn't know about ConstraintLayout @ThalesIsidoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` is a good option because it gives us much more precise control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/crime_button"
        tools:text="Crime Title Crime Title Crime Title Crime Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Crime Date" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/crime_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Crime Button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output will be: 
[image: first example]

In this case, the first `TextView` is linked to the `top` of the `Button`, and the second `TextView` is linked to the `bottom` of the `Button`. But it will only have a nice result if we know the fixed height of all the components, so it's ideal to put a maximum of lines in the `TextView`, as I did in the example code itself.

Another example allowing multiple lines for the TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/crime_date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Crime Title Crime Title Crime Title Crime Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title"
        tools:text="Crime Date Crime Date Crime Date Crime Date" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/crime_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Crime Button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output will be: 
[image: second example]

In this second case, the `TextViews` are linked only to the `parent`, so the `ConstraintLayout` will scale its size, and as the `Button` is also linked to the `parent`, it will stay in the middle.

There are still other possible scenarios, where it could be necessary to use a great resource of `ConstraintLayout` called [chainStyle](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html), if you still need something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED] You can use ConstraintLayout as a root. If you convert your button to AppCompatButton, you can reach your goal.
[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crime Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/crime_title"
        android:text="Crime Date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/crime_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/crime_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/crime_title" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/crime_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/crime_title"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/crime_title"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/crime_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/crime_title" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: But in your case the button is still beyond the border )

Comment: Got you. Let me update the code. Sorry for my wrong.

Comment: Could you try again? @VanechikSpace

Comment: same thing @Enes Zor

Comment: which border? border of crime_date? @VanechikSpace

Comment: yeah. The button is still like on yout picture but i need the button to match the date border

Comment: bro I have updated again. If it is not okay too, please give me more detail with some demonstrations.

Comment: Thanks for help. Look at the first picture that has been provided by @Thales Isidoro. I have needed this one.